# Nodejs: url.parse issue with arrays inside query

Tags: node.js, query-string

```
http://domain.com/action?params[]=1&params[]=2&params[]=3
```

returns:

```
query: { 'params[]': [ '1', '2', '3' ] }
```

`params[]` as name instead of `params`?

After PHP it's kinda surprise.

jQuery serialization is adding `[]` on parameters btw.

Are you guys wrote a helper for this or I'm just doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This module does parsing as required:

https://github.com/visionmedia/node-querystring

There is another one for complex arrays if this doesn't work:

https://github.com/jazzychad/querystring.node.js

Both found here:
https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/modules

Comment: Yes indeed. The default Node.js decided not to implement the feature for params with multiple values, but TJ's module solves that.

Comment: Guess Ry shouldn't be bothered with such misc issues atm.

Comment: Yeah probably it's ok to leave this out of the core and into a separate module.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like expected behavior to me; I would be more surprised if the querystring parser *removed* part of the name.  That is, the module is doing exactly what I would expect from a parser which simply splits name/value pairs by '`&`' and name/value by '`=`' (and unescapes special characters).

```js
var qs = require('querystring');

qs.parse('params=1&params=2&params=3'); // Name should be "params"
// => { 'params': ['1', '2', '3'] }

qs.parse('params[]=1&params[]=2&params[]=3'); // Name should be "params[]"
// => { 'params[]': ['1', '2', '3'] }
```

Comment: Mate i'm using jQuery and params serialization is taken by it. It's sending this params[]=1&params[]=2&params[]=3 type of query.

Comment: I have found a module for this. Question is closed. :)

Comment: A little observation is that, naturally, if you pass only one parameter using params=1 it will not be parsed as an array.